# Nuclear Energy vs. Ion Energy

Tags: energy

One of the alternatives for the burning of fossil fuels is to generate heat and electricity via nuclear energy.  It was one of the most promising, so nothing can go wrong, right?

[image]
**Fukushima**

<sup>(picture replaced on 2016-09-28 to show the actual Fukushima Daichi plant, not Chiba Oil Refinery on fire)</sup>

[image: Picture showing a building with the center destroyed]
**Chernobyl.**

The sources of nuclear power--and with it, nuclear catastrophe--are radioactive elements.  Strontium-90.  Plutonium-239.  Iodine-131.  Cobalt-60.  Caesium-137.  Elements that, if left alone in a Life After People, can make the environment toxic for thousands if not millions of years.

So, in this alternate scenario, no one brought up nuclear energy.  Instead, what the engineers conjured up is ion energy, energy coming from the fourth element of the universe--plasma, supercharged gas particles.

Will an energy system based on plasmatic rather than nuclear energy avert the issues of radiation burns/poisoning?  Will there still be any dangerous radiation at all, in the event of a major accident?  While we're at it, which gas would be the best to ionize into the desired energy?

Comment: ?? how are you getting energy from plasma, its a state of matter, like liquid.  Are you going to heat it up and then convert the heat to other types of energy, that will lose energy.  Nuclear reactors convert mass to energy the nuclear reactions do the conversion and also emit radiation.   We need more detail on how this energy is created before we could say what side effects it would have

Comment: More detail on what?

Comment: Ion Energy doesn't actually exist, so you need to explain what it is and how it theoretically works before anyone can tell you about its effects.

Comment: Where are you going to get the plasma from?  Solar, gas, coal, and nuclear power all get power from pre-existing sources (either the sun or the ground.  Also worth noting that all of the power sources we dig out of the ground are relatively stable during transport and storage, and the one that isn't dug out of the ground (solar) is constantly grappling with the difficulty of transport and storage.

Comment: @CortAmmon  If you'd reread the question, I'd asked which gas would be best to ionize.

Comment: Why do you believe that you can get energy out of a gas by ionizing it?  There's a lot of fake perpetual motion machines which center around building their energy bearing fuel (like splitting water into hydrogen and oxygen) and then trying to use that fuel (turning it back into water) to create energy.

Comment: First picture is not the Fukushima reactor site at all. Fukushima., Three Mile Island and indeed all Western reactors are inside hardened containment domes. As well, unlike the reactors at Chernobyl, Western reactors are generally water moderated, so the most extreme event is a "steam explosion" followed by the molten reactor core dropping into a pit under the dome.

Comment: You need to spend energy to produce and maintain a plasma. It isn't a stable state. Which process do you want to do with the ions to produce energy? But maybe a quick answer to that, are you familiar with nuclear fusion (and the ITER project)?

Comment: For what it's worth, [here are some photos of the actual Fukushima Daiichi site](http://businessbearing.com/a-nuclear-reactor-operator-returns-to-the-fukushima-plant/) and also [here are some high-resolution aerial photos](https://cryptome.org/eyeball/daiichi-npp/daiichi-photos.htm) taken 1-2 weeks after the disaster. Additionally [Wikipedia has some material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukushima_Daiichi_nuclear_disaster).

Comment: I think that by ion/plasma energy he means nuclear fusion, turning hydrogen into helium in a very exothermic reaction, it does involve first turning the hydrogen into a plasma.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I am sorry but your post is word salad, combined with lots of nonsense reasoning about nuclear power. To respond: obligatory xkcd reference https://xkcd.com/1162/ Second, your rant on accidents, as Thucydides and MichaelKjörling posted out the first picture is not even a NPP, it is an oil refinery. And nuclear power is actually the **safest** form of energy, accidents included. http://www.forbes.com/sites/jamesconca/2012/06/10/energys-deathprint-a-price-always-paid/ And last: "we ionize matter and then we get energy, woo hoo!!!". Wait, what?! Extreme hand-waving right there.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors  You've clearly not seen Life After People, have you?  Besides, you are also late because Thucydides already gave me a satisfying answer.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I know of it. But what is your point here? So you saw a speculative drama documentary, where the premise itself makes the concept of safety entirely moot because humans have been **eradicated**. Ok... so what?! What is your argument? When not assuming such a premise, then nuclear power remains the safest form of generating usable energy on Earth, and your rant with its insinuation is entirely irrelevant. The most dangerous forms of energy on Earth are: fossil fuels, burning biomass and hydro power. Nuclear accidents makes for spectacular news, but not widespread death and injury.

Comment: Have you actually visited Chernobyl?  The Red Forest is one of the most dangerous places to visit.  The radiation is trapped in the soil, preventing decomposition.  Would a lightning bolt hit it, the flames would spread the radiation to the atmosphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using nuclear energy to ionize gas and then passing it through an MHD conversion unit is a possible way to increase the efficiency of a nuclear reactor by bypassing the Carnot limit.

Nuclear fissile materials can also be ground into a fine powder and induced into a reactor chamber makes for a "Fission Fragment" reactor, where the effect is to make the fissile material into ionized gas. As a rocket, this has a theoretical exhaust velocity of .03 *c*, but collisions inside the chamber between particles tend to reduce the effective exhaust to .01 *c*. As a power generating system, the high velocity exhaust can also be passed through an MHD system for a very high powered reactor.
[image: FFRE]

So Ionization allows for a more efficient conversion of the thermal energy of a nuclear reactor to energy (or rocket thrust), but does not replace or eliminate nuclear energy.

Some links were requested:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission_fragment_reactor

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission-fragment_rocket

http://nextbigfuture.com/2010/03/dusty-plasma-based-fission-fragment.html

http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/718391main_Werka_2011_PhI_FFRE.pdf

http://crowlspace.com/?p=2389

Much of the attention to this concept has been given to rocket applications, rather than ground based reactors.

Answer (score 4):

No. You will get **no more** energy out of the ionized gas than you put in to ionize it. In practice it will be much less. The law of the [conservation of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy) states that you can't generate energy, you can only transform it.

There is energy inherent in chemical bonds between atoms, which can be released e.g. by burning hydrocarbons.

There is energy inherent in the core of an atom which can be released by fission (in some cases) or fusion (in other cases).

Heating the fuel or operating medium to plasma won't change this basic principle.

Comment: I have the feeling that the question was asked without much research or previous knowledge on what energy source is or what a power plant works on. This answer (negating the validity of the question and pointing to the first law of thermodynamics) is the only helpful one. I have the feeling that people should be taught the three laws of thermodynamics from high school. It explains almost everything, and defines clearly what is possible and what is not.